# Dont open project from github

Tags: termux

I download project from github in my Termux terminal, but after download, when I pass the command "`сd /*projectname*`" termux said me: `No such file or directory`

I tried find this project in file manager in my Android, but the all folders in /com.Termux are empty.

Then I'm pass the command `git clone https:/github.com/developer_name/project_name` and Termux told me - `destination path *projectname* already exist and is not an empty directory`

Ive got 2 question

1. How I can open *projectname* in Termux?
2. Which full path from downloaded project from github?

Comment: try cd \*projectname*, *not* /*projectname*

Comment: Thank u, its help.

Comment: @Red did it fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

use (apt-update && apt upgrade) first then other commands

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).